# How best to validate state transitions

Tags: validation, sails.js, waterline

I've created a sails model with a 'state' attribute:

```
state: {
        type: 'string',
        defaultsTo: 'created',
        enum: ['created', 'pending', 'completed', 'rejected' ]
    },
```

I've constrained the attribute to finite states by using the 'enum' key.  Now, I'd like a solution for constraining the state transitions.

I've considered doing a .find() in the afterValidate() so that I can look at the before->after transition.

What is the best way to constrain state transitions using waterline/sailsjs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for what purpose this `state` attribute is. But I believe [Lifecycle Callbacks on Models](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html) are a great place. There you have `afterValidate()` (as you already mentioned), `afterCreate()` etc. which are triggered when a model changes or created.

Comment: The 'state' field is used to track the current state of a ticketed item (document).  I.e. a ticket is either 'created', 'pending', 'completed' or 'rejected'.  Obviously the states may vary.  Therefore one user may create an item and another user may process it (and eventually close it).

Comment: The reason I posed the question is I figured it's not a rare problem.  I.e. it seems like it would be popular in CMSs where items have a lifecycle.

Comment: Is this answer helpful?